# PHP WooCommerce removing p tag from string

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, str-replace

Using WooCommerce for Wordpress I have created Product Attributes and I have a line of values that I'm using `;` as a seperator to split the line into `<td>` which works but the problem is that Wordpress keeps adding `<p>` tags to the output.

Looking at the Output HTML it seems to wrap the first `$applies[0]` with `<p></p>` and then `$applies[3]` has `<p></p>` after it. When I would much prefer to have all `<p>` removed from the string.

I tried `echo str_replace("<p>","",$apply);` and `$applied = preg_replace('#<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;?)*</p>#', '', $apply);` but still no luck.

**PHP**

```
<tr class="<?php if ( ( $alt = $alt * -1 ) == 1 ) echo 'alt'; ?>">
<th><?php echo $woocommerce->attribute_label( $attribute['name'] ); ?></th>
<td><?php
    if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {  
        $values = woocommerce_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], 'names' );
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
    } else {
        //Convert pipes to commas and display values
        $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );
        $apply = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
        $applies = explode(";", $apply);
        echo $applies[0]."</td><td>";
        if ($applies[2] != ''){
            echo "<font style='text-decoration:line-through'>".$applies[1]."</font></td><td>";
        } else {
            echo $applies[1]."</td><td>";
        }
        echo $applies[2]."</td><td>";
            $applies3 = str_replace(' ', '', $applies[3]);
            $applies3 = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $applies3);
        echo $applies[3];
    }
        ?></td>
    </tr>
```

**Output HTML**

```
<tr class="">
    <th>Container</th>
    <td><p>W2300 x D1030 x H940mm</p></td><td> £19953</td><td></td><td> in stock<p></p></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Changed**

`$apply = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );`

**To**

`$apply = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ), $attribute, $values );`

By removing `wpautop()` from this line it will remove the `<p>` tags.